# dataTables columnFilter no way to enter data for column filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

The page shows foot with column names but no places to enter the values for column filters.
I looked to the examples on the data tables web site and others in the stack overflow website and found no clue how to fix it.
Any help or suggestion how to fix this will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

```erb
<% provide(:title, 'TBMs Daily Progress') %>

<% if signed_in? %>

    <h3>TBMs Max Station by day - Today's date: <%=@current_date%></h3>

  <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
      <h6 class="error-message">
          <%= "Today's location for TBM W is not loaded" %>
          <%= " Last TBM W recorded date was: " %>
          <%=@tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
      </h6>
  <% end %>

  <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
      <h6 class="error-message">
          <%= "Today's location for TBM E is not loaded" %>
          <%= " Last TBM E recorded date was: " %>
          <%=@tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
      </h6>
  <% end %>

    <p>
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
            <%= link_to "Add new location", new_tbms_progress_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "List view", tbms_progresses_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
    </p>

    <table id="progresstable" class="display table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead style="background-color: #bbbbbb;">
            <tr>
                <th>Daily Date</th>
                <th>TBM ID</th>
                <th>Max Station</th>
                <th>TBM Status</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @tbms_progresses.each do |tbms_progress| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= tbms_progress.daily_date %></td>
                    <td><%= tbms_progress.tbm_id %></td>
                    <td><%= number_with_precision tbms_progress.max_station, precision: 2 %>
                    <td><%= tbms_progress.tbm_status %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to tbms_progress.id, tbms_progress %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Daily Date</th>
                <th>TBM ID</th>
                <th>Max Station</th>
                <th>TBM Status</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <h6>Legend: W aka TBM1 or 26900, E aka TBM2 or 27000</h6>

<% else %>
    <%= render 'instruments/unsigned' %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready
  (function() 
      {
        $('#progresstable').dataTable
        (
            {
                /*sPaginationType: "full_numbers",*/
                bJQueryUI: true,
                aaSorting: [ [0,"desc"], [1, "desc"] ],
                bDeferRender: true,
                bStateSave: true
            }
        ).columnFilter
        (
            {aoColumns: 
                [
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" }
                ]
            }
        );
      }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to do individual column filtering like here:https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html ? In that case you should at least add some input fields to your footer and implenet the rest of the exapmle code.

Comment: Why can't be done in a simpler way just like here: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5033/datatables-column-filter-add-on-for-the-data-table/p1 . The author claims: "This code adds simple text filters in the footer of the table."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving to the data tables 1.10.2, not using anymore bootstrap layout for the tables and I running the scripts for data tables from //cdn.datatables.net on each page containing a table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't know a plugin like this existed.

I have checked it out and it works perfectly good.
[Look for yourself](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9vGyqFfyM6fSYzgAUPT?p=preview)

Only thing i can imagine ist that you did not include the plugincode from [here](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js) after jquery and datatables code has loaded, but before you start the initialisation.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-semver="2.0.3" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
  <link data-require="datatables@*" data-semver="1.9.4" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
  <script data-require="datatables@*" data-semver="1.9.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="colfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code in the example is pure html. I am using Ruby on Rails. Another detail (may be important, I don't know) is that the provided example is using data tables version 1.9.4. I don't know how to get this version through my Gemfile. I am getting always jquery-datatables-rails (1.12.2) in my gems list. Any attempt to specify version 1.9.4 for data tables in the Gemfile is followed by this error: Could not find gem 'jquery-datatables-rails (= 1.9.4) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

Comment: I am not a ruby programmer, but js is js, so there should be some way to get this running. May be you just resort to the (not so) complicated way of using simple input fields in the footer and link them to the sorting function. Really not so hard, trust me. Just look at the example (about 20 lines of simple jquery code and only 1 line (#12) that is actually related to datatables). Good luck, sorry that I couldn't help you any more.