# jQuery Datatable Search Single Column

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable

I have checked several examples of how to search a single or multiple columns on a datatable and it seemed like using the .ColumnFilter() option would be the best.  Chrome console stops at the .columnFilter() line and says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

if I remove the .columnfilter() piece the page loads fine and the click event fires, but no search occurs. is my understanding of how this search and columnfilter work wrong?

```
    $('#listings').dataTable({
        "data": props,
        "searching": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "oTableTools": { "sRowSelect": "single" },
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Type",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "defaultContent": "" },
            { "title": "Address",
            "defaultContent": "" },
            { "title": "City",
            "defaultContent": "" },
            { "title": "State",
            "defaultContent": "" },
            { "title": "Zip",
            "defaultContent": "" },
            { "title": "Beds",
            "bSearchable": true,
            "defaultContent": "" }]
                      }).columnFilter();

    var table = $('#listings').DataTable(); 
    $('.bed_column_filter').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function searchBeds() {
            var value = this.getAttribute("data-value");
            table
                .column(5)
                .search( value )
                .draw();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Day 3 of attempting, no success.. I have ensured I am loading the jquery plugins in the correct order, included the columnfilter plugin, included the tabletools plugin, nothing is helping, yet every example I read uses the methods above, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could not get this to work either but I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146240/datatables-columnfilter-no-way-to-enter-data-for-column-filtering/22167279#22167279 and it worked.  The difference is downgrading DataTable to version 1.9.4 and now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is late for this user. But I came here while searching similar problem.
Here is [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4100/how-i-search-only-first-column) which works for me.

In Datatable , there are setting as

```
"aoColumns": [{ "bSearchable": true }, { "bSearchable": true }, { "bSearchable": false }, { "bSearchable": false }],
```

You can set true/false value for column search enable/disable.